# How can customize namespace cycle detection with NDepend

Tags: c#, ndepend

NDepend offers a `ContainsNamespaceDependencyCycle` function which is very helpful. However, sometimes I have an exception to this rule. For example, often I have a `Helpers` namespace which is allowed to be referenced from any other namespace and of course, also is allowed to reference types from its parent namespace.

It is unclear to me yet, how to exclude e.g. the `Helpers` namespace from `ContainsNamespaceDependencyCycle`. I was looking at the [Avoid namespaces dependency cycles](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/Q_Avoid_namespaces_dependency_cycles.html) example, but also there I'm not sure how and if it can be extended to exclude certain namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that we have a [default code rule](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_namespaces_dependency_cycles.html) that can be customized, just for Namespace Dependency Cycle  detection? and another one for [Namespace Mutually Dependents](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_namespaces_mutually_dependent.html) that are often the roots of dependency cycles.

Comment: Yes, the first one is the one I was mention in my question. The second one I haven't seen so far. Would have an example *how* to customize these rules?

Comment: This is C# LINQ code, I would advise editing this rule and changing it a bit to see how results will evolve depending on your need?  Hopefully the CQLinq engine compile / run / show result for you live when editing a query

Comment: You mean a little bit of trial and error. I guess if it was that easy, there would be examples out there.